# No GATT characteristics discovered for dual-mode Bluetooth (Smart Ready) device

Tags: linux, bluetooth, dbus, bluez, gatt

I'm running some of the Python example code from Bluez using the DBUS interface.  I am on Fedora 28, Bluez 5.50.  The device I am trying to connect to is a dual-mode Microchip BM78.  Both the sample code and bluetoothctl will discover the device, show both the LE and BDEDR services, but neither detect the the GATT characterstics once services are resolved.  The GATT characteristics are not resolved, even after the device is paired, trusted and/or connected.

The Bluez DBUS API seems to require that the characterists are first discovered before any attempt to read or write is possible.

I can connect to the device using non-DBUS APIs and access the characteristics just fine.

Is there some way to force characteristic discovery once a service is resolved?  Or some way to connect to a known characteristic that has not be discovered using the DBUS interface?